# MVC Password Recovery with GeneratePasswordResetToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, password-recovery

I am developing a system of password recovery with sending token. I'm following the lead of Microsoft but I don't understand some things:

- 1. Create a password-reset page that has a field where users can enter their email address.
- 2. When a user has entered his or her email address in the password-reset page, verify that the email address represents a valid
     user. If it does, generate a password reset token by calling the
     GeneratePasswordResetToken(String, Int32) method.
- 3. Create a hyperlink that points to a confirmation page in your site and that includes the token as a query-string parameter in the link's
     URL.
- 4. Send the link to a user in an email message. When the user receives the email message, he or she can click the link to invoke the
     confirmation page.
- 5. Create a confirmation page that extracts the token from the URL parameter and that lets the user enter a new password.
- 6. When the user submits the new password, call the ResetPassword(String, String) method and pass the password reset token
     and the new password. If the token is valid, the password will be
     reset. If the token is not valid (for example, it has expired),
     display an error message.

Now, I managed to get to the point 3 but I do not know how to implement it since all the guides I've seen aren't working.

The code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult InvioPassword(FormCollection form)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage", "Account");
            }

            var email = form["email"];
            var ttf = new TocFruit();
            var psw = ttf.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerEmail.Equals(email));
        string esito = "";
            if (psw != null)
            {
                Email.RecuperaPassword(email, psw.Comment);
                esito = "Gentile cliente le abbiamo inviato una mail al suo indirizzo di posta con la sua password.";
            }
        else
        {
            esito = "Mail non esistente...";
        }
        ViewBag.esitoMail = esito;
            return View();
        }

    public static void RecuperaPassword(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            //generate password token
            var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email);
            //create url with above token
            var resetLink = "<a href='" + Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { un = email, rt = token }, "http") + "'>Reset Password</a>";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, have someone a solution?